# How can a create a NiFi workflow for - Forward all the files to next processor only when we get Request.json from the previous processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am working on writing a NiFi workflow and stuck in a scenario where I have to get a few files with different formats. But all the files will be routed to next processor only when we get the json file.
Thanks

Comment: Start with reading the json file, and then read the other